# Office js Worksheet object

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I have a general query about the worksheet object of Office js. The object has property called 'id'.Is there any way we can make sure that every time a particular sheet gets loaded, the ID generated is always the same?
Can we assign a fixed value to the 'id' property?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A worksheet ID (and any other ID in the API model, for that matter) is **read-only**.  So you can't assign it.  However (as with any other ID in the API model), the whole purpose of an ID is that it is in fact **unique**, at least for the duration of the session.

So, the caveats are:

- The uniqueness is only guaranteed **per Office session**.  That is, if the user closes the workbook and then re-opens it, the IDs *might* be different.
- Some IDs are stronger than others.  Generally, any ID that is a GUID is going to be unique and never be re-used within the same session.  However, there are some objects (tables) whose ID, for now, is just a number / stringified-number; in those cases, the number might get re-used by another table if the original one is deleted and a new one added.  But so long as the table is alive, its ID won't get re-used, at least for the currently-opened Office session.

Comment: Is there a reason not to have a read-only worksheet codename that persists across sessions (like VBA)? The codename is unique within a workbook and a workbook is unique within a session.

Comment: I suggest you file this as a bug/suggestion on https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues.  It is definitely a valid scenario, I think that the were some technical issues at the time, but they might not be relevant anymore.  And I think the scenario makes even more sense in the case of the REST APIs.  Please post a link back here once you have filed it.